# access is denied when stopping WebClientService

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to stop WebClientService programatically but I do not have permission.

```
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
foreach (ServiceController service in services)
{
    if (service.ServiceName == "WebClientService")
    {
        service.Stop();
    }
}
```